# How does Python Re Module work in this examle?

Tags: python, regex

What is the process of matching this regular expression? I don't get why the explicit group is 'c'. This is piece of code is taken from Python Re Module Doc.

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
>>> m.group()
'abc'
>>> m.groups()
('c',)
```

Also, what about:

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc]+)", "abc")
>>> m.group()
'abc'
>>> m.groups()
('abc',)
```

And:

```
>>> m = re.match("([abc])", "abc")
>>> m.group()
'a'
>>> m.groups()
('a',)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
re.match("([abc])+", "abc")
```

Matches a group consisting of a, b or c. The group at the end of that is the last character found in the character class as matching is greedy so, ends up with the last matching character which is `c`.

```
m = re.match("([abc]+)", "abc")
```

Matches a group that contains one or more consecutive occurences of a, b or c. The matching group at the end is the largest contingious  group of a, b or c.

```
re.match("([abc])", "abc")
```

Matches either a, b or c. The match group will always be the first matching character at the start of the string.

Comment: Always weird to post at the same time as someone else!  +1

Answer (score 3):

In your first example, `([abc])+` creates a group for each a, b, or c character it finds.  c is the explicit group because it's the last character that the regex matches:

```
>>> re.match("([abc])+", "abca").groups()
('a',)
```

In your second example, you're creating one group that matches one or more a's, b's, or c's in a row.  Thus, you create one group for `abc`.  If we extend `abc`, the group will extend with the string:

```
>>> re.match("([abc]+)", "abca").groups()
('abca',)
```

In your third example, the regex is searching for exactly one character that is either an a, a b, or a c.  Since a is the first character in `abc`, you get an a.  This changes if we change the first character in the string:

```
>>> re.match("([abc])", "cba").group()
'c'
```

Comment: Nice example of extending the second example's group +1